# More efficient way of recreating elements with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HTML table, where each row is clickable and acts as an accordion. When the row is clicked, a few elements (another table, a few other div elements, etc) are visible underneath each row. Here is a fiddle with that functionality:

http://jsfiddle.net/7dfwrje7/5/

The problem is, if I had n number of rows, I'd have to append the code for the hidden elements to each row in order for it to work, that is, this code:

```
   <tr>
      <td colspan="6">
        <input id="row1" type="checkbox">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th>Phone Number</th>
            <td>555-3226</td>
            <th>City:</th>
            <td>New York</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Hire Date:</th>
            <td>8/13/12</td>
            <th>Salary:</th>
            <td>$48,000</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
```

In addition, I would have to give this input a new ID each time a row is generated:

```
<input id="row1" type="checkbox">
```

I have a loop which I've written in JavaScript to do all of that. New table rows are created in each iteration and I have code that manually creates each element for this HTML and appends it to each generated row:

```
        <tr>
          <td colspan="6">
            <input id="row1" type="checkbox">
            <table>
              <tr>
                <th>Phone Number</th>
                <td>555-3226</td>
                <th>City:</th>
                <td>New York</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th>Hire Date:</th>
                <td>8/13/12</td>
                <th>Salary:</th>
                <td>$48,000</td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
```

So within the loop creating all the rows, I have something like:

```
var createRow = document.createElement("TR");
 var createCell = docment.createElement("TD");
 tbody.appendChild(createRow);
 tbody.appendChild(createCell);

etc.....
```

And I have so much html to create this way, so there are about 100-200 lines of JavaScript code creating those elements. All of this is working for me, but my question: is there a better and more efficient way of doing this, instead of recreating every single HTML element in my JavaScript code? Both, efficient in terms of writing less code to do all of this and efficient in terms of performance?  I'm trying to stick to pure JavaScript, no libraries. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `copy_tr = parent_tr_node.cloneNode(true);` then going through the children to set the values will probably be cheaper. Similarly you could wite a _function_ and pass in the stuff you want each time. Furthermore, is it really necessary to have nested tables?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. And yes, I know nested tables don't perform great but in this case I need to have them.

Comment: Would createDocumentFragment help? http://jsperf.com/createelement-vs-createdocumentfragment

Comment: I think fragment and element will be the same in terms of writing code... Can you show your code? The fiddle has no js. The way you are phrasing sound more a case of grouping your code so you can reuse more parts of itself.

Comment: Avoid boilerplate with the use of loops, create function that will return your elements, I'm not sure about every js interpreter, but I believe that `element.cloneNode()` is still one of the lighter way of creating element's clones.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I've learned something new from each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your jsFiddle, I understand that you implemented the accordion opening functionality by a strange trick: a label that covers the entire row, with CSS pseudo class on the corresponding input to reveal the table.

This is fun because it does not involve script, but it requires creating more elements and using unique id's per input (hence your problem of having to assign unique id's). It also prevents copying the row text, and you still have an extra line on the hidden row (which is actually a row with height 0 because it is empty). Finally, the nested table must be already created.

Since anyway you will need scripting to generate your main table, why not using [event listening](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) on the table rows to perform this? You could even generate the nested table on demand (when the user clicks on a row), so that you do not have to create them at table initialization. This saves you some time on the main table processing.

As for generating the main table, refer to [this comparison](https://jsperf.com/innerhtml-vs-createelement-test) about performance. It shows 2 fastest methods:

- Generating a string of HTML code, then filling an `element.innerHTML` at the end.
- Using a generated element (or document fragment, or cloned node) outside the DOM, filling it with other elements as needed, then inserting it in the DOM at the end.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7dfwrje7/7/ (I used the HTML string method)

Comment: Thank you for your help, I took this approach